# Audit Changes in Column in Spring Boot

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I'm making a project where my requirement is to send emails to those users who hadn't updated their password in 28 days.

Now for that, I need to audit the changes for the password update. But from what I searched online all I do is to audit the changes in whole column.

Is it possible to audit the changes of a column rather than a whole row?

```
@LastModifiedDate
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
protected java.util.Date lastModifiedDate;
```

This piece of code audit the changes of a column so this will not work because if the admin changes the user detail then `lastModifiedDate` will also change then the email triggered after 28 days from then not when the user changes his password.

Any help would be grateful.

Apologies for my English as it is not my first language.

Comment: Maybe add new column `lastPasswordChangeDate`

Comment: Hi, Giga. That was my first thought as well. But how will data persist into that?

Comment: update field when person decides to change password, like `set password='password', password_change_date = now()`

Comment: Hey mate, it turned out it can be implemented by your logic. Thanks, man. Also, I want to ask that now it's just a logical problem rather than what I asked should I delete the question or answer my own question? I don't know how things are done here when this type of problem happens.